# Is a glass habitat on Mars viable?

Tags: spacex, mars, radiation, habitat

In Elon Musk's recent Reddit AMA (ask me anything), he talked about

> Initially, glass panes with carbon fiber frames

For colonization of Mars.

My question:
Does a glass roof provide sufficient protection for plants/humans [against radiation] to create edible food on Mars?

Extra credit:
Is ISRU glass production possible with minimal manufacturing capabilities?    Or is spaceX forced to transport the glass?   (Isn't glass heavy, and non-maleable making it difficult to transport?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to filter out all radiation, of course - that's the point of using a transparent material. You want to filter out the high-energy part (UV) while leaving lower frequencies (visible light). Glass can do that, even better than air.

This doesn't filter out very high energy radiation which on earth are shielded by the magnetic field, but for crops that's probably not a major issue. They don't grow old anyway.

Glass is chiefly made from silicon and oxygen. As it happens, those are *incredibly* common on Mars, even more than iron. However, if we'd only use those, we'd get a problem with UV. With no additives, we'd make fused quartz, and that is very transparent to UV. Normal glass contains also a sizeable fraction of sodium oxide (soda) and calcium oxide (lime). Those two are fairly common on Mars.

Making glass is not too hard: melt the ingredients, mix, pour on a hot tin bath, let it cool.

Comment: Some resources: http://web.archive.org/web/20061206083416/http://aerospacescholars.jsc.nasa.gov/HAS/cirr/em/6/6.cfm, http://web.archive.org/web/20070101085134/http://science.nasa.gov/NEWHOME/headlines/space98pdf/fiber.pdf, https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20140008714

Comment: Also there is radiation shielding glass on Earth: https://www.corning.com/worldwide/en/products/advanced-optics/product-materials/specialty-glass-and-glass-ceramics/radiation-shielding-glass.html Not sure how difficult it would be to make or what it would protect against.

Comment: Radiation shielding glass is used in plants that process nuclear fuel. You'd need lots of it to protect against cosmic rays (which have higher energies), I wonder how transparent it would be at the required thickness.

Comment: @Hobbes: You need a thick pane when the requirements are to shield a running nuclear plant, but that's because you need a 99.99999% attenuation or so. (Yes, that's 7 nines.) The thickness is not tied to the photon energy but the photon count.